# Place Python list in Excel column

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

Say I have two lists in Python:

```
A_List=["jim", "go"]
B_List=["kkj", "nmh",123]
```

how can I get those lists into a .csv Excel file, where in column A, A1 contains `jim`, B2 contains `nmh`, A2 contains `go`.

In other words, each list's items needs to go into a column in Excel, with each list item in a separate cell.

Comment: `A1` contains what?Also, how B1 is `nhm` ? where is `nhm` come from, guessing its a typo for `nmh` , what happenned to `kkj` ?

Comment: I fixed the typos, and I want all everything in the csv file including kkj. Kkj should go in B1

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Use zip to create the rows. Since your lists are unequal in length, use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to create blank entries for the end of the shorter list.

Use [`csv.csvwriter.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) to write the CSV data to a file.

```
import csv
import itertools

A_List=["jim", "go"]
B_List=["kkj", "nmh",123]

with open("result.csv", "w") as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    writer.writerows(itertools.izip_longest(A_List, B_List))
```

Result:

```
jim,kkj
go,nmh
,123
```